# Sharing variables on python

Tags: python

I am trying to play an audio on python and update the variable "Flag" (if the audio is playing update to 1 or if audio has stopped update to 0) so I can continously share the variable value on another script and then send it to a csv file. However I am new to python and the only way I've shared variables is with Global, and in this case I want to share a variable from a function within a function. How can I achieve this?

This is my code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sched,time,random,pickle
from pygame import mixer
def soundlib():
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep) 
    mixer.init(48000, -16, 1, 1024) #Frequency,size, 1:mono,channels,buffer

    def main():
        name="C:/whitenoise4.wav" 
        global sound
        sound=mixer.Sound(name)
        x=sound.get_length() #segundos que dura audio
        s.enter(5, 1, play, ()) #esperamos 5s para reproducir
        s.enter(5+x, 1, stop, ()) #10s de reproducción
        s.enter(18,1,main,()) #Tiempo de silencio: 20s-(5+x)
    def play():
        sound.play()
        global Flag
        Flag=1
        return Flag
    def stop():
        Flag=0
        return Flag

    main()
    s.run()
```

Script 2

```
import multiprocessing
from soundlibrary4 import *

soundlib()
```

So far it only plays the audio but it doesn't change the Flag state nor does it print the currentstate.

Comment: If you're trying to communicate between two scripts, then you're looking at a lot more work than what you might be prepared to do at this point. You should reconsider your approach and move the work you're trying to do in both scripts into one script and use something like a global variable to do what you're tying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use global in other file like this.
one is using class variable. and other is using global variable.

classA.py

```
g_Var=0


class Player:
    flag=0
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def play(self):
        global g_Var
        print('play')
        Player.flag=1
        g_Var=1

    def stop(self):
        global g_Var
        print('stop')
        Player.flag=0
        g_Var=0

    def status(self):
        print('player flag=', Player.flag, ' g_Var=', g_Var)


if __name__=="__main__":
    print('main in classA')
    A = Player()
    A.status()
    A.play()
    A.status()
    A.stop()
    A.status()
```

classATest.py

```
import classA

def main():
    print('g_Var access in classATest = ', classA.g_Var)

A = classA.Player()
A.status()
A.play()
A.status()
A.stop()
A.status()

B = classA.Player()
B.status()
A.play()
A.status()
B.status()

A.stop()
A.status()
B.status()

B.play()
A.status()
B.status()
main()

B.stop()
A.status()
B.status()
main()
```

and the output is

```
player flag= 0  g_Var= 0
play
player flag= 1  g_Var= 1
stop
player flag= 0  g_Var= 0
player flag= 0  g_Var= 0
play
player flag= 1  g_Var= 1
player flag= 1  g_Var= 1
stop
player flag= 0  g_Var= 0
player flag= 0  g_Var= 0
play
player flag= 1  g_Var= 1
player flag= 1  g_Var= 1
g_Var access in classATest =  1
stop
player flag= 0  g_Var= 0
player flag= 0  g_Var= 0
g_Var access in classATest =  0
```

and you can change the global var.

```
def turnon():
    print('turn on')
    classA.g_Var=1
    classA.Player.flag=1

def turnoff():
    print('turn off')
    classA.g_Var=0
    classA.Player.flag=0
```